# Session window gapDuration in Apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I was looking to understand how session window works in apache beam. Let's say I have the following scenario.

1. I specify a session window with gapDuration of 4 hours.
2. Event 1 with key abc occurs now. A new session is created for this key and this session would last now + 4 hours.
3. Event 2 with key abc occurs at now + 3 hours. So it belongs to the same session.
4. I have a trigger set up to AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow().

Will this trigger occur at now + 4 hours or the session is extended due to the event that occurs at now + 3 hours and hence the trigger occurs at now + 3 + 4 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session window would trigger at `now + 3 + 4` (i.e., after you had a `gapSize` period of time without new elements for that key).

Session windows are called "mergable windows" since they can be extended and don't have a fixed size as FixedWindows or SlidingWindows.

If you want more info, there's this [talk](https://youtu.be/HKPpohFFDoY?t=426) I gave about Windows in **Apache Beam Learning Month**

Comment: Well explained the concept in the talk.